# Linking domain name, server, DNS server?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, domain-name-system, domain, nameserver

I think I've got myself a bit lost here. Basically I have a private server, a .com domain registered at one place, and using clouDNS.net as a DNS server. I tried hosting my own DNS server but it got a bit too confusing.

My domain register has the clouDNS nameservers set up, and at clouDNS I have the nameservers linked to my domain, but where do I link the domain to my server IP address?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want reverse DNS to be working? i.e. `nslookup 1.2.3.4` returning `server.example.com`

Comment: I think I currently have domain.com -> DNS linked, but nothing pointing to my actual server. I have just added an 'A' Record (I had none) which I think may be my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add records for your server. A simple lookup requires at least an `A` (IPv4) or `AAAA` (IPv6) record to exist, for mail and other services one can set up others. For subdomains this is valid too, just repeat that.

I think a simple how-to on configuring DNS might help you out. For example [this one](https://help.hover.com/entries/21204757-how-to-edit-dns-records-a-cname-mx-txt-and-srv).